# Group incoming and outgoing invoices to make their sum 0

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've faced an interesting problem today, and decided to write an algorithm in C# to solve it.

There are incoming invoices with negative totals and outgoing invoices with positive totals. The task is to make groups out of these invoices, where the total of the invoices adds up to exactly 0. Each group can contain unlimited members, so if there are two positive and one negative members but they total value is 0, it's okay.

We try to minimize the sum of the remaining invoices' totals, and there are no other constraints at all.

I'm wondering if this problem could be traced back to a known problem, and if not, which would be the most effective way to do this. The naive approach would be to separate incoming and outgoing invoices into two different groups, sort by total, then to try add invoices one by one until zero is reached or the sign has changed. However, this presumes that the invoices in a group should be approximately of the same magnitude, which is not true (one huge incoming invoice could be put against 10 smaller outgoing ones)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is a well known and studied one, and is called **[The Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)**.

Unfortunately, the problem is [NP-Complet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)e, so **there is no known polynomial solution for it**<sup>1</sup>.

In fact, there is no known polynomial solution to even determine if such a subset (even a single one) exists, let alone find it.

However, if your input consists of relatively small (absolute value) integers, there is a pretty efficient (pseudo polynomial) [**dynamic programming solution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) that can be utilized to solve the problem.

If this is not the case some **other alternatives** are:

1. Using exponential solution like [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) (you might be able to optimize it using [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) technique)
2. Heuristical solutions, such as [Steepest Ascent Hill Climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) or [Genethic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)s.
3. [Approximation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm)s

---

(1) And most computer science researchers believe one does not exist, this is basically the [P VS NP Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of this. I'm going to research the articles you suggested!